The Lo-ammi periods principle?
When reading Appendixes to The Companion Bible by Dr. E.W. Bullinger (See the "Lo-Ammi" periods chart, 50. vii.11). I learned of the so called Lo Ammi principle, based off
Hosea 1:9 (KJV)

Then said God, Call his name Loammi: for ye are not my people, and I will not be your God.

The basis of this principle is that when Israel is in servitude to the gentiles; God clock stops concerning Israel, and during these periods, the Nation is in a state of astrangement from God, in fufillment of its Nationl covenantal blessings.
So when we come to Acts 13:16-22 the Apostle Paul gives a computation regarding Israels History. When we add this up (40 yrs.= in the wilderness; 450 yrs.= Judges period;40 yrs.= Saul’s rein; 40yrs=David’s rein, cp.1 Ki.2:11= total 570 yrs.).
Then when we turn to 1 Kings 6:1; there is a difference in the number of years given concerning Paul’s computation, as will be seen when added up, that there is a 93 year difference.
It says in the 480th year after the children of Israel came out of Egypt that in the fourth year of Solomon’s rein that in the second month that he began to build the temple (1 Kings 6:1). Solomon=3 yrs. bring us to the 480th yr. after the people left Egypt.
I found the following answer to this seeming issue, in the the book "Alphabetical Analysis" lo ammi, by Charles H Welch; (which gives a detailed summary, for further investigation to any questions that may arise, and is freely accessible online). Where the answer to this 93 yr. difference, is that the Nation was judged by God during the Judges period. Because when we add up those periods, the total comes to the exact number of 93 (Jud.3:8=8yrs; 3:14=18yrs; 4:3=20yrs; 6:1=7yrs; 13:1=40yrs =93yrs.) showing us that when Israel is in a servitude, the prophetic clock stops.
Is this the answer to the discrepancy of times; and was this God's way of implying in the book of Acts, that His dealings with National Israel began to be put on hold?
The Apostle Paul quotes from Hosea 1.9:
Romans 9:26 And it shall come to pass, that in the place where it was said unto them, Ye are not my people; there shall they be called the children of the living God.
Is this the reason for Paul’s giving of the world's time, and not God’s time clock with Israel, in Acts 13, where his ministry to the gentiles began? And does this principle effect our understanding of the time fufillment of prophetic events?

This question can only be answered from a Christian perspective, it is much better suited to Christianity.SE

It just so happens that I have the Bullinger 'Companion Bible' with Appendixes. I understand that this Anglican theologian lived from 1837 to 1913. This work was published in 1922/3. The particular appendix you seem to base your question on is on page 70 of the Appendixes at the back. Unfortunately the one referred to is a facsimile of handwriting; the black ink is a touch patchy against the mid-grey background.
However, it is critically important to know just what Bullinger says about "The 'LO-AMMI Periods" heading his page. Is this a principle that can be used to deal with a claimed "discrepancy of times" in the O.T.? Does this claimed 'principle' really give grounds for claiming this "was God's way of implying in the book of Acts, that His dealings with National Israel began to be put on hold? Is this the reason for Paul’s giving of the world's time, and not God’s time clock with Israel? And does this principle effect, our understanding of the time fufillment of prophetic events?" These are the questions put to those who would answer. So, with glasses on, and magnifying glass in hand, I will now transcribe what the learned gentleman neatly wrote in italic script in his Appendix, after he has quoted Hosea 1:9.

"When Israel was regarded by Jehovah as 'Lo-Ammi' i.e. Not My People
(cf.Hos 1.8 & 2.1) then, Jehovah dealt with them on a different
principle in recording time. During these periods their national
history years are omitted from the years of the world's lifetime.
When they were Lo-Ammi, the events recorded in the Scriptures, were
recorded according to a reckoning we have termed Anno Dei (in
GOD's years) and not according to Anno mundi (in the year of the
world) reckoning.
Herein is the key to a right understanding of Biblical Chronology; and
it will be found, when rightly applied to unlock many 'difficulties'
and to remove many supposed 'discrepancies' between certain passages
in Scripture." [Reference as above]

He then gives 3 enumerated examples from the Old Testament. In Number 1 he says "there are five Lo-Ammi periods, during which Jehovah 'sold' his people into the hand if their enemies" (and give dates and events). In Number 2 he says "there are three Lo-Ammi" periods ( and details them). In Number 3 he details the final period. His conclusion begins:

"Through taking the 450th y. of 1 K.G.1 [? writing unclear] as an
Anno Mundi date, instead of as it is - an Anno Dei reckoning, confusion has resulted all down the line, and many
interesting and important facts escape notice in consequence." (Ibid.)

[Then gives an example of David's first anointing, calculating something that is claimed to lead to David and 917 years after Isaac became the seed of Abraham. This is then said to give 1,000 years to the anointing of Christ at the Jordan inn A.D. 26.]
Trusting I have not overlooked details that could link the question to Bullinger's Appendix here, I can only say that there is no apparent connection to the calculations suggested by the O.P. regarding the book of Acts, and Paul's statement about Israel.
This is, certainly, a concluding sentence of Bullinger that the O.P. is free to take up and run with. It is:

"By noting the 'LO-AMMI' periods, many other important details will
come to light." [I capitalise where he does, and put in bold italics
words he has underlined, which I cannot do here.]

However, my answer is that I see nothing in Bullinger's Appendix that warrants any link to what Paul says in Acts, or elsewhere, about the nation of Israel. If there is, the onus is on the O.P. to explain how any apparent 'principle' has been applied according to Bullinger's intentions regarding distinctions between events recorded in the Scriptures:

"recorded according to a reckoning we have termed Anno Dei (in
GOD's years) and not according to Anno mundi (in the year of the
world) reckoning."


You will find more info in connection to Acts, in the Charles h. Welch reference. And the appendix is in digital form for free on a few sites.

@ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory  No doubt. Where ever possible I prefer to work from printed literature, for then I know which edition of an original piece of writing I have, and that it has not been digitally tampered with. Further, in this day of AI-generated 'stuff', caution is needed regarding on-line material, even on here where AI-answers have been spotted. At least, on here, everybody knows my Qs & As are not AI-generated. (No aspersions implied!)

It was mostly for others. E. W Bullenger covers the Judges periods, in his lo ammi appendix,  Charles Welch furthers his work, with Pauls reference to those times, thats the link. Seems like you are somehow missing the connection.  Did you not look up the Charles Welch reference mabye I should put it on here.

I believe g. h. pember, was the first to bring out the idea

The finding of the OP is indeed intriguing, but it seems more like a coincidence. If God intended to exclude the years of the Israelite's iniquity from the count, He would have excluded the 40 years of wandering during the Exodus, where an entire generation of Israelites perished.
Furthermore, the period of oppression by enemies during the time of Judges was not limited to just 93 years. This time frame only accounts for the oppression under five of the judges, whereas there were a total of twelve judges. Each judge was raised as a deliverer when the Israelites repented. Therefore it is likely that the count is incomplete.
I don't see any principle suggesting that whenever the Israelite sinned, God's time clock paused. Humanity is under God's judgement every day, as Paul states in Romans 3:23, "for all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God". There isn't a situation where someone sins more, causing God to pause His clock.

Sorry I added my references.
